# How to speed up my code? Python

Tags: python, performance

I need my code to work faster, this one I currently have sometimes even takes up to 5 seconds to print an answer.

```
import math 

n, k = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
myList = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
range_is = math.factorial(n) / (math.factorial(3) * math.factorial(n-3))
range_is = int(range_is)

answer_list = []
q = 0
w = 1
e = 2

for l in range(range_is):
    o = myList[q]+myList[w]+myList[e]
    answer_list.append(o)
    if e == n-1 and w == n-2  and q != n-3:
        q = q+1
        w = q+1
        e = w+1

    elif e == n-1 and w != n-2: 
        w = w+1
        e = w+1

    elif e != n:
        e = e+1  

answer_list.sort()
print(answer_list[k-1])
```

How can I make it run faster? And what is the problem in this code, so I can avoid this problem in the future?

Comment: 1. Assuming this code is working correctly it may belong on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) - but make sure to read the rules and guidelines there first. 2. What is this code even supposed to do? Also please make sure to use *sensible* variable names, `e`,`w` and `q` don't explain what their purpose is

Comment: One important piece of info is missing : What should your code do?

Comment: First you can use math to simplify all your use of the factorials with `n*(n-1)*(n-2)/6`. Although, most likely you want that number `3` there to be variable I guess. Also, `for` loops in python are slow, as are append operations. go and check `numpy` for better performance numerical manipulations

Comment: It's not clear what your code is actually doing and what it suppose to do. Please get rid off magic numbers, change one letter variables for some more descriptive names and put some additional explanation what is the meaning behind your code. The biggest problem is probably with factorials, as it's pretty heavy operation, but it's hard to say without any examples and explanations.

Comment: Also, since you use `input()`, it's impossible to reproduce your problem

Comment: The code is supposed to take in two integers n and k. N is how big your list should be. K is the place of the number you want to print in the list.

Comment: in the second line you write n number of integers, and this program will add all possible trios of those numbers, and save them one after another in new list

Comment: So tell us what the input is. Or replace `input()` by an example string.

Comment: For example:
first line- 5 4
second line- 1 2 3 4 5
this program will first add 1 to 2 and 3, next 1 to 2 and 4, and so on
It then saves all those numbers in a list and then prints fourth number saved in the list

Comment: Write all these comments as information in your question and don't litter the comments.

Answer (score 2):

## What should be written in your question

To summarize:

- You have a list of `n` integers.
- You want to calculate every combination of `p` integers.
- You want to calculate the sum of every combination.
- You want to sort those sums.
- You want the `k`-th sum.

## Code with `itertools.combinations`

With this description, the code becomes straightforward:

```
from itertools import combinations

n = 5
p = 3
k = 4

integers = range(1, n + 1)
triples = combinations(integers, p)
# [(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
triple_sums = [sum(t) for t in triples]
# [6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 9, 10, 11, 12]
triple_sums.sort()
# [6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12]
print(triple_sums[k - 1])
# 8
```

Using [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) might speed your code up, especially since you don't need to calculate `math.factorial(n)` for large `n`.

Most of all, this code is much more concise and shows your intent much better.

## Performance

It's unfortunate that `triple_sums` isn't sorted even if `integers` are sorted. Every combination needs to be calculated, and the whole list has to be sorted. There might be an alternative way to produce the combinations with which `triple_sums` would be sorted directly but I cannot think of any.

If your list has 7000 integers, there will be `57142169000` triples. Using `itertools` won't help much for performance. You'd need to provide more information about the list and `k`.

Comment: sorry, but this didn't speed it up at all

Comment: @erikvalkovic: How large is `n`?

Comment: sometimes up to 7000

Comment: @erikvalkovic: How large is k?

Comment: Despite bad description, problem is quite interesting. It's not that simple algorithmic problem as for example, finding k-th triplet sorted in lexicographic order (what I thought at the first time), cause even for ascending natural numbers sum of such triplet isn't always sum that we're looking for. It's probably doable to write in O(nlogn) time complexity using min-heap, but I don't have working implementation yet.

Comment: Which is far more optimistic that worst case in current implementation which is O(min(n^k, n^(n-k)).

Comment: @erhesto I'd be really interested to see such an algorithm. Indeed, the current one is really bad.

Answer (score -4):

Some advice:

1，Using python 2 instead of python 3.

2,When calculating large numbers，
Using "xrange" instead of "range";
Using "ifilter" instead of "filter".

3,If you use iterative algorithms, try to use "yield".

Comment: Python 2 isn't going to help anything here.

Comment: *"python 3 still not as fast as python 2"* - what's your source/proof for this statement?

Comment: `import timeit`
`import random`
 
def generate(num):
while num:
yield random.randrange(10)
num -= 1
 
def create_list(num):
numbers = []
while num:
numbers.append(random.randrange(10))
num -= 1
return numbers
print(timeit.timeit("sum(generate(999))", setup="from __main__ import generate", number=1000))
>>> 0.88098192215 #Python 2.7
>>> 1.416813850402832 #Python 3.2
print(timeit.timeit("sum(create_list(999))", setup="from __main__ import create_list", number=1000))
>>> 0.924163103104 #Python 2.7
>>> 1.5026731491088867 #Python 3.2`

Comment: Rather than show some arbitrary micro-benchmark you created (using a very old version of Python 3) you should check out a proper benchmark, such as: https://speed.python.org/comparison/ which shows that the newest versions of Python 3 are pretty much as fast as Python 2.7 (in some cases even faster)

Comment: @SamL Are you comparing to Python 3.2, which was never widely used?

Comment: Changing versions always leads to some strange problems, so I'm still using python 2.7